# How to ensure only specific type of ReactElement can be passed to Component props in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

`eslint` and vscode won't show any validation error on passing incompatible ReactElement type. I couldn't find how to validate this in any docs or examples.Nothing I tried works.

```
// Footer.tsx

export interface FooterProps {
    /**
     * footer primary button text
     */
    primaryButtonText: string;

}

class Footer extends PureComponent<FooterProps> {
  // render Footer here
}

// Modal.tsx

interface ModalProps {
  footer: ReactElement<FooterProps>;
}


class Modal extends PureComponent<ModalProps>{
   //render modal here
}


// Text.tsx

interface TextProps{
  color: string;
}

class Text extends PureComponent<TextProps>{
   //render Text
}

App.tsx

<Modal footer={<Footer primaryButtonText="hello world" />}  // This expected to work since footer receives the correct type and it works.

<Modal footer={<Text title="hello world" />} // expected to fail as footer receives incorrect type, but there is no any validation error, in fact doesn't matter which element you pass no error will occur.
```

Versions:

```
"typescript": "^3.7.2"
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
"eslint": "^6.7.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by limiting your `ModalProps` to:

```
interface ModalProps {
  footer: Text<FooterProps> | Footer<FooterProps>;
}
```

In the above written code. Typescript should complain if `footer` get's anything else than `Text` or `Footer`.

Comment: Hi, This was my first try, typescript complains on this definition "Type 'Footer' is not generic".